# Dynamic HTTP Inbound Channel Adapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am trying to create a dynamic Http inbound channel adapters with different paths which are generated by database values.

I am using the same principals used in [https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-ftp].

The dynamic context looks like the following:

```
   <context:property-placeholder />

   <int-http:inbound-channel-adapter id="dynamicInboundEdi846HttpRequest" channel="dynamicInboundEdi846HttpChannel" auto-startup="${startup}"
                                     path="${url}" supported-methods="POST"/>

   <int:header-enricher input-channel="dynamicInboundEdi846HttpChannel" output-channel="${successChannel}">
      <int:header name="tsp" value="${tsp}"/>
   </int:header-enricher>

   <bean id="multipartResolver" class="com.bstonetech.ptms.integration.service.http.CustomMultipartResolver"/>


   <int:channel id="dynamicInboundEdi846HttpChannel"/>
   <int:channel id="inboundDynamEdiHttpErrorChannel"/>
```

The dynamic adapter code is as follows:

```
public class DynamicHttpAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
   private static ApplicationContext context;
   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DynamicHttpAdapter.class);

   @Override
   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
      context = applicationContext;
   }

   @Autowired
   private IFileService fileService;

   private final Map<String , ConfigurableApplicationContext> contexts =
           new HashMap<String , ConfigurableApplicationContext>();

   private List<String> tspMap;

   public DynamicHttpAdapter(List<String> tspMap) {
      this.tspMap = tspMap;
   }

   public String resolve(String name, String propType, String autostartProp,String successChannel) {
      /* loop through tsps and see if we have a context already deifined */
      for (String tsp : tspMap) {
         String key = tsp + propType;
         if (!contexts.containsKey(tsp)) {
            log.debug("create context for: " + key);
            createNewTspContext(name, propType, tsp, autostartProp, successChannel);
         }
      }
      return "done";

   }

   private synchronized void createNewTspContext(String name, String propType, String tsp, String autostartProp,
                                                 String successChannel) {

      ConfigurableApplicationContext httpContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
              new String[] { "/META-INF/spring/integration/dynamic-http-inbound-adapter-context.xml" },
              false, context);

      if (this.setEnvironmentForTsp(httpContext, name, propType, tsp, autostartProp, successChannel)) {
         httpContext.refresh();
         String key = tsp + propType;
         this.contexts.put(tsp, httpContext);
      }

   }

   /**
    */
   private Boolean setEnvironmentForTsp(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx, String name, String propType, String tsp, String autostartProp, String successChannel) {
      StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
      Properties httpProps = new Properties();
      // populate properties for tsp
      httpProps.setProperty("startup", fileService.getPropertyForTsp(tsp,autostartProp, propType));
      httpProps.setProperty("tsp", tsp);
      httpProps.setProperty("successChannel", successChannel);
      httpProps.setProperty("url", "/" + tsp.toLowerCase() + "/" + name);

      PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("httpProps", httpProps);
      env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
      ctx.setEnvironment(env);
      return true;

   }

   public Map<String , ConfigurableApplicationContext> getContexts(){
      return contexts;
   }
```

A *ConfigurableApplicationContext* is created, the properties set and the context added to the *ApplicationContext*.

An IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping is initiated with the correct handler and mapping.

However, when a request comes in the *IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping* is not detected in the *DispatcherServlet*. There is an *IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping*  which is present in the *DispatcherServlet* but i has no mappings.

I suspect this is because the dynamic context is a child and cannot be seen by the *DispatcherServlet*?

Is there any way make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could add the mappings, the `DispatcherServlet` does not have visibility to the beans in the child contexts so it couldn't invoke the handler(s).

It's probably easier to have a single inbound endpoint and add a router to route to different channels, based on the path variable(s).